# Publisher's sink is triggered twice

Tags: swift, combine

I was wondering is it the expected behaviour for a subscriber to have its sink triggered twice when in this scenario?

```
func testExample() throws {
    let service = MockAPIService(isSuccessful: true)
    let sut = ContentViewModel(apiService: service)
    let fetchImagesExpectation = expectation(description: "Fetching images")
    
    sut.$images
        .sink { value in
            print("## count: ", value?.count)
            // fetchImagesExpectation.fulfill()
            // XCTAssertEqual(value?.count ?? 0, 5)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    sut.fetch()
    wait(for: [fetchImagesExpectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

Console output:

```
## count:  nil
## count:  Optional(5)
```

Here is ContentViewModel:

```
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private (set) var images: [ImageModel]?
    private let apiService: NetworkingService
    private var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable>
    
    init(apiService: NetworkingService = APIService()) {
        self.cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        self.apiService = apiService
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        apiService.fetchImages()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                if case let .failure(error) = result {
                    Logger.logError(error)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
                self?.handleRespose(response)
            })
            .store(in: &cancellable)
    }
    
    private func handleRespose(_ response: SampleImagesResponse) {
        guard let responseImages = response.sample else {
            return
        }
        
        self.images = responseImages.compactMap { item in
            if let urlString = item.imageURL,
               let url = URL(string: urlString),
               let imageID = item.id,
               let title = item.description {
                return ImageModel(imageID: imageID, title: title, url: url)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

When `sut.fetch()` is commented console is still printing `## count:  nil`.

Comment: Arguably, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973316/swift-combine-how-to-skip-an-event/63973359#63973359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it the expected behaviour for a subscriber to have its sink triggered twice when in this scenario?

Yes. The `nil` value arises from merely connecting the `sink` to the `$images` in the first place, as you can readily discover by means of this much simpler scenario (no test, no ObservableObject, no `fetch`, no ImageModel, no nothing):

```
import UIKit
import Combine

final class ContentViewModel {
    @Published private (set) var images: [Int]?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ContentViewModel().$images.sink { value in print(value) }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

That prints `nil`. This behavior is simply a feature of `@Published`, as I explain in my [online book](https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/publishers/publisherspublished.html):

> the values emitted will be *the initial value at subscription time* followed by new values when the property changes [emphasis mine]

If you don't want to receive that value, insert a `dropFirst()` operator before the `sink`.